# how to model sphere with 3 color layer

Tags: texturing, transparency, color

I am very new to 3D modelling and a bit lost. Can anybody tell me how to build something like this in attachement? I did 3 spheres with transparency but the result of colours doesn't correspond to my pattern. The first picture is the patter how the result color should be and the second one is my result and if I set up transparency in Blender then the green color is quite dark but I need the more like in the first picture. Thanks in advanced[image: this is my patter how the result should be]

[image: this is my currect model(if I set up trasparency, then the green colour inside is quite dark)]

Comment: you might get a better result with a single Mesh using Gradient Texture set to Quadratic Sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129044/3d-volume-from-2d-texture/129147#129147

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring since Blender has a system of "Normals" for calculating the outside part and the inside part of the faces. If you Tab into Edit Mode, go to "Shading and UVs", then click on a button that says "Flip Normals". Those dark bits you are seeing will be reversed to the other side.